# xpath to fetch siblings in enlisted menu

Tags: xml, xpath

Good day everyone ! i am not too good at xpathing, but created an xml structure of this sort:

```
<Pages>          <!--This is the root node-->

    <Home>
        <description>This is my site</description>  
        <url>views/home/home.php</url>   
        <menu>
            <item>Help</item>
            <item>About</item>
            <item>Contact</item>
        </menu>
    </Home>

    <Help>             <!--i need to select this if its listed in Home/menu/item above-->  
          ...
             some stuffy child nodes
          ...
    </Help> 

    <About>            <!--And Or select this if its listed in Home/menu/item above-->
          ...
             some stuffy child nodes
          ...
    </About>

    <Contact>          <!--And Or select this if its listed in Home/menu/item above-->
          ...
             some stuffy child nodes
          ...
    </Contact>

</Pages>
```

i've been dieing with an xpath expression that selects Home 
(excluding its menu child; if possible) and any other page
(say About and/or Contact) which is listed in Home/menu/*; that is, 
any sibling of Home that is enlisted (itemised) in Home's menu child.
currently, here is what i can think :

```
$SimpleObj = new XMLManager('thefile.xml')  //my custom class that creates and manages xml DOM 

$SimpleObj->Xpath("Pages/*[name() = 'Home' and ./name() != 'menu'] | Pages/*[name() = ./menu/item[./text()] ] ");
```

the above expression proved abbortive. what sin have i commited ? or am i asking for something impossible ?
any guide will be greately appreciated. thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible XPath :

```
/Pages/*[self::Home or name()=preceding-sibling::Home/menu/item]
```

The above XPath selects all child element of `Pages` if it is a `<Home>` element*, or it is an element having name equals one of the `Home/menu/item` element value.

*) You can't exclude any element from a parent element using XPath since `Home` element along with it's content is one unit. XPath returns unit(s) of the source XML as it is.